# Пустая ошибка в юнити при создании проекта

Tags: unity3d

При создании проекта выдается пустая ошибка и больше ничего. Пробовал переустанавливать юнити не помогло
[image: сама ошибка]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну уж unity он такой, когда у меня ещё был линукс (Эх хорошие были времена) проект вообще с 5 раза создавался. Теперь изучаю godot.

Answer (score 0):

Информации мало. но я поделюсь тем как я это исправил, у меня было тоже самое. но Unity даже движок скачивать не хотел, а готовый выдавал эту-же ошибку.

1. попробуй скачать другую версию Unity
2. если не помогло то протестируй на виртуальной машине (я использую VirtualBox т.к. он бесплатный)
3. если на Виртуалке работает то значит дело в винде - я пересел с Win7 на Win10. и оно заработало, но ты можешь попробовать просто переустановить свою